# Why not to double number of registers for fast syscalls?

Tags: operating-system, cpu-architecture

We are facing two facts:
1. Syscalls are expensive. Program should save its state on stack, trap to kernel, which causes cache and TLB invalidation, etc etc.
2. With new technologies(like 14nm) we have plenty of space on chips.

Why not to have two sets of registers and two TLBs? One for userspace processes and another for kernel. Each syscall would just switch processor from userspace registers+tlb to kernel's, which should be really fast.

Clearly I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some processor architectures have had shadow registers.  For instance, the Z80, on interrupt, switches to an alternate register file.  One of the things limiting the register file size is clock period.  If the rename table gets too big, that'll slow down a pipeline stage in the front end.

TLBs generally have high hit rates, because each entry corresponds to a whole page, and they can typically tag entries for more than one address space.  The TLB miss overhead for your first system call may be high, but if you're making lots and lots of system calls, your TLB is likely to retain mappings for kernel memory.

Answer (score 0):

Registers are used to exchange values in system calls. Some systems have a kernel mode stack, so the stack cannot be used to exchange values.